# Does this criteria prove that Y calls X in infinite recursion?

Tags: c, recursion, terminate

The purpose of this question is to determine the minimum correct halt status criteria required to detect infinite recursion, when we assume that the functions involved are pure functions (thus computable functions).

```
#include <stdint.h>
typedef void(*ptr)(); 

void X(ptr P, ptr I)  
{
  P(I); 
}

void Y(ptr P)  
{
  X(P, P);
}

int main()
{
  X(Y, Y);
}
```

Does that fact that Y calls its caller with the same parameters as its caller prove that Y is calling X in infinite recursion?

**When we assume that Y is a pure function**
If there were any conditional branch instructions in Y prior to its call to X it seems to be proved that they didn't make any difference.

**In computer programming, a pure function is a function that has the following properties:**

(1) the function return values are identical for identical arguments (no variation with local static variables, non-local variables, mutable reference arguments or input streams), and

(2) the function has no side effects (no mutation of local static variables, non-local variables, mutable reference arguments or input/output streams).
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function

**Computable functions** are the basic objects of study in computability theory. Computable functions are the formalized analogue of the intuitive notion of algorithms, in the sense that a function is computable if there exists an algorithm that can do the job of the function, i.e. given an input of the function domain it can return the corresponding output.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_function#

Comment: You've answered your own question. So what are you asking here? Which [*criteria*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/criteria) are you referring to?

Comment: Examination of assembly does not prove anything. You are probably required to prove it formally.

Comment: @trincot This criteria: "An examination its x86 machine language proves that Y calls X with its same parameters and there are no conditional branch instructions between the invocation of Y and its call to X."

Comment: You can easily do this by manually "expanding" the calls. `X(Y,Y)` performs call `P(I)`, where `P=Y` and `I=Y`, so it becomes `Y(Y)`. This performs call `X(P, P)`, where `P=Y`. So it becomes `X(Y,Y)`. So we are back to the initial call.

Comment: Just expand the recursive calls starting from `main`, and you will soon see if it's infinite. It will be both easier and more correct than using the generated assembly.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Because x86 machine language has precisely defined semantics the actual execution trace would seem to be a formal proof of the behavior of Y(). I have that yet refrained from posting it because it is a little long.

Comment: @polcot, ok that is strange use of the word ["criteria"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/criteria). What you quote there is a [*statement*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/statement) or [*assertion*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/assertion).

Comment: @interjay Yes your example trace at the C level seems to prove this point very well. **I need a program to see this too, that is why I referred to the x86 level.**

Comment: @polcott You will first need to prove that the assembly is equivalent to this C code.

Comment: So now you have two things to prove ;-)

Comment: @polcott A general method of detecting infinite recursion from a program is impossible (equivalent to solving the halting problem).

Comment: @EugeneSh. The assembly was generated from the C code.

Comment: @interjay I only need to examine this single case.

Comment: @polcott It doesn't mean anything. Compilers may have bugs, or your program might have undefined behavior. If you are asked for a formal proof, you will have to present the proof that neither of it exist. You have a very simple proof I presented in my second comment.

Comment: If you only need this one case then you already know the answer (it's infinite), so why do you need a program to do it? It isn't clear what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: @interjay I need to know that the halt status criteria at the x86 level is correct. It seems that this halt status criteria might always be correct in the general case as long as the functions are pure. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function In other words it seems that no counter-examples exist that show that this criteria is ever incorrect.

Comment: What @interjay is meaning (I guess) is that you can't conclude that a program is not terminating just by observing it's running time, even if it is very long.

Comment: @EugeneSh. In many cases there are non-halting behavior patterns that can be matched that prove that a computation is non-halting. The above criteria seems to handle every case of simple infinite recursion where simple means that no conditional branch instructions are involved.

Comment: You keep saying "criteria", without stating what criteria you mean. If you mean the criteria that the functions are pure, then it does not apply to your case, as they are not returning values for at least some cases, which is violating the first property in your Wiki link.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Every case where one function Y calls its caller X with the same parameters as its caller and there are no conditional branch instructions involved can be determined to specify infinite recursion at the point where Y first calls X.

Comment: @polcott, you seem to have come here with an assertion instead of a question. Maybe a misunderstanding of what Stack Overflow is about.

Comment: Since `main` doesn't _use_ the return value (and neither do the others) is it valid for the problem to replace the return types of `X` and `Y` with `void` (and remove the `return` statements)? This would be the first step in a proof (which I believe is possible).

Comment: @CraigEstey Yes that would be valid.

Comment: "*Because x86 machine language has precisely defined semantics*" — are you saying then that C doesn't have defined semantics (because it does)?  But if C doesn't have defined semantics, then how does translating to a "more precise" assembly language help you speak to the C code?

Comment: @ErikEidt From what I recall C has some ambiguities. The x86 language has zero ambiguities.

Comment: First I doubt that, but second, if that's the case, then how does solving a different problem (assembly) prove something about the C code?

Comment: @ErikEidt I changed my question to only refer to the C code to eliminate extraneous complexity. None-the-less termination analyzers such as this one https://aprove.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/interface/v-AProVE2023/c must translate C into something that can be more easily processed by other programs.

Comment: If C has ambiguities, then a translation to a more precise form is just one possible translation.  Because of that proving something about the more precise form does not prove something about the more lax form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256747/discussion-between-polcott-and-erik-eidt).

Comment: _"Does that fact that Y calls its caller with the same parameters as its caller prove that Y is calling X in infinite recursion? What about when we add the fact that neither Y nor X have any conditional branch instructions?"_ No and no. Consider: `int Z(ptr P) { exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); return 0; }`, then in `main`: `X(Z, Z);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since main doesn't *use* the return value (and neither do the others) is it valid for the problem to replace the return types of `X` and `Y` with `void` (and remove the `return` statements)? This would be the first step in a proof (which I believe is possible). –
> Craig Estey

> Yes that would be valid. –
> polcott

*Caveat:* I've never done a *formal* proof before, but I'll make an attempt using code equivalent substitutions that I understand.

---

Summary of steps:

1. original code
2. convert return types to void and remove return statements
3. because all calls to X use the same value for each argument,
   convert X to use a single argument
4. inline X into Y
5. replace all Y with X because they are the same
6. remove Y
7. since X is called (only in main) with argument X, replace the
   argument to X in X with X (i.e. P --> X)
8. since X no longer depends on its argument, remove the argument

---

```
// step1 -- original code

#include <stdint.h>
typedef int (*ptr) ();

int
X(ptr P, ptr I)
{
    P(I);
    return 0;
}

int
Y(ptr P)
{
    X(P, P);
    return 1;
}

int
main()
{
    X(Y, Y);
}
```

---

```
// step2 -- convert return types to void and remove return statements

#include <stdint.h>
typedef void (*ptr) ();

void
X(ptr P, ptr I)
{
    P(I);
}

void
Y(ptr P)
{
    X(P, P);
}

int
main()
{
    X(Y, Y);
}
```

---

```
// step3 -- because all calls to X use the same value for each argument,
// convert X to use a single argument

#include <stdint.h>
typedef void (*ptr) ();

void
X(ptr P)
{
    P(P);
}

void
Y(ptr P)
{
    X(P);
}

int
main()
{
    X(Y);
}
```

---

```
// step4 -- inline X into Y

#include <stdint.h>
typedef void (*ptr) ();

void
X(ptr P)
{
    P(P);
}

void
Y(ptr P)
{
    P(P);
}

int
main()
{
    X(Y);
}
```

---

```
// step5 -- replace all Y with X because they are the same

#include <stdint.h>
typedef void (*ptr) ();

void
X(ptr P)
{
    P(P);
}

void
Y(ptr P)
{
    P(P);
}

int
main()
{
    X(X);
}
```

---

```
// step6 -- remove Y

#include <stdint.h>
typedef void (*ptr) ();

void
X(ptr P)
{
    P(P);
}

int
main()
{
    X(X);
}
```

---

```
// step7 -- since X is called (only in main) with argument X, replace the
// argument to X in X with X (i.e. P --> X)

#include <stdint.h>
typedef void (*ptr) ();

void
X(ptr P)
{
    X(X);
}

int
main()
{
    X(X);
}
```

---

```
// step8 -- since X no longer depends on its argument, remove the argument

#include <stdint.h>
typedef void (*ptr) ();

void
X(void)
{
    X();
}

int
main()
{
    X();
}
```

---

In the final step, `main` calls `X`. And, `X` just calls itself [infinitely].

---

**UPDATE:**

> The original X and Y are reduced to X calling itself, thus proving that Y calls X in infinite recursion. What I really need to know is whether or not it can be correctly determined that Y calls X in infinite recursion on the basis that Y is calling its caller with the same parameters as it caller. –
> polcott

I'm not totally sure I understand what you're requesting. But, I think it's implied by [or a byproduct of] the proof above.

Perhaps, if we redo step (5) as:

```
// alt5 -- replace X(Y) in main with Y(X)

#include <stdint.h>
typedef void (*ptr) ();

void
X(ptr P)
{
    P(P);
}

void
Y(ptr P)
{
    P(P);
}

int
main()
{
    Y(X);
}
```

Now, we can try:

```
// alt6 -- replace [undo] P(P) in Y with X(P)

#include <stdint.h>
typedef void (*ptr) ();

void
X(ptr P)
{
    P(P);
}

void
Y(ptr P)
{
    X(P);
}

int
main()
{
    Y(X);
}
```

We end up with a calling sequence:

1. main -> Y(X)
2. Y(X) -> X(X)
3. X(X) -> X(X)

I don't know, but it *may* be more clear if we branched off after step (3) and changed `main` from `X(Y)` to `Y(X)`

Comment: The original X and Y are reduced to X calling itself, thus proving that Y calls X in infinite recursion. What I really need to know is whether or not it can be correctly determined that Y calls X in infinite recursion on the basis that Y is calling its caller with the same parameters as it caller.